# RExcel clashes when attempting to download a file in csv format

Tags: csv, rexcel

I am working on an Excel file that has embedded RExcel and calls a function from R through RApply in thousands of cells. The problem that I encounter is when I try to download some files in CSV format, I obtained a message which states that a severe error has occured and all my Excel files are shut down.

I would appreciate some assistance in what I could do in order to prevent this problem!

Comment: Does the error message says anything else?

Comment: Hi Rafal,unforunately the messgae it is not very informative. "Microsoft Excel has stopped working"